# Android No SDK Found / NULL Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, motorola-emdk

All,

Android Studio, in the layout rendering pane on the right, I get the error message:

"No Android SDK found. Please configure an Android SDK."

Also, next to the Android icon at the top it says "".

I have tried running with "Administrator" permissions.

I have checked the SDK setting to be correct:

```
File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location.
```

I have checked that I have the SDK installed and the path configured in the project structure.

The project builds with no errors or warnings.

This project runs correctly on my Windows 7 machine.  I moved the project over to a new Windows 10 machine and am now having these problems.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I have a serious headache from banging my head against the wall.

My configuration:
Android Studio 1.5.1
Windows 10.
I downloaded the AS package, IDE and SDK together.

The project uses the Motorola Symbol EMDK library which requires the Android 4.4.2 (API 19) SDK.

Under "Project Structure" there is:

```
"Compile SDK Version": "EMDK 4.0 (API 19) (Symbol Technologies LLC) (API 19).
"Build Tools Version": "23.0.2"
```

From the SDK manager, I have verified that the following are installed:

```
Android SDK Tools 24.4.1
Android SDK Platform-tools 23.1
Android SDK Build-tools 23.0.2
Android SDK Build-tools 23.0.1
Android 6.0 (API 23) SDK Platform
Android 6.0 (API 23) Google APIs
Android 6.0 (API 23) Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image
Android 4.4.2 (API 19) SDK Platform
Android 4.4.2 (API 19) EMDK 4.0 (API 19)
Android 4.4.2 (API 16) SDK Platform
Android 4.4.2 (API 16) EMDK 4.0 (API 16)
Android Support Repository 25
Android Support Library 23.1.1
Google Repository 24
Google USB Driver 11
Intel HAXM 6.0.1
```

Comment: The SDK location is probably pointing to the SDK location of the old machine. Go to File -> Project Structure and set the path to the SDK location on the new machine.

Comment: I just created a new project, using API 23, Rendering is fine.  But only shows API on the rendering level icon.  Not 19.  A new project, also created from scratch, using API 19, exhibits the problem.  Something about the system cannot find 19.  Even though it appears to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the Android bundle.  Installing the SDK and IDE separately solved the issue.

```
Uninstall Android Studio Bundle.
Download the SDK and install.
Download the IDE and install.
Copy the EMDK add-ons manually to the SDK add-ons folder.
```

All seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (platform emdk api 19 not found), I have it resolved by following a "manual" refresh of the emdk plugin, here's what I did:

Go to "project structure" then Modules then app then "Properties", change the "compile sdk version" from "emdk 19" to "api 19 android", compile, then change it back to "emdk 19". Then compile again. This time finally the IDE is able to find "emdk 19".